# SSRS subreport parameter - multi values

Tags: reporting-services, subreport

as you can see below, i need to pass a parameter value (red arrow)
i tried to use this expression: =iif(Parameters!Country.Count = Parameters!CountryCount.Value, Nothing, Join(Parameters!Country.Value,","))
but im receiving an error when im try to run the report (Error: Subreport could not be shown.)

can you please assist and guide me how to pass multi value parameter?
country - manually list i created (not from DB / SQL)

[76021-untitled.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzMXf.png)

Comment: If you pass nothing to your subreport, then how do you expect it to run and return something? Is your subreport allowed to run with nothing as a paramter?

Comment: As Harry mentioned, you would need the parameter's **Allow Null value** box to be checked in order for it to allow for the NOTHING. If the parameter is using Available values, NULL must be one of those Available values.